# ASP .Net WebService

Tags: asp.net, web-services

What happens if the webservice gets time out before the client actually gets the response.what happens if the client retries to call the webservice function before it gets the response for the previous call because of time out.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on which SOAP client you are using, however most of them will throw some type of exception if a timeout occurs, and they usually do not automatically retry on timeout.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.Here client is not getting the response even if they retry.In our service we have a db call as well.What happens to the previous call if the client retries.Will that be still in process.?

Comment: Yes, just like an HTTP call, web service calls are stateless so each request will be treated as a brand new call.

Answer (score 0):

Webservice requests are asynchronous, so a retry (although it won't on its own) will initiate a different thread/process, which might create undesirable issues as far as business logic is concerned. If the webservice times out before the client receives the response, it will throw a timeout error to the client.